# Where does CardIO (with phonegap plugin) process image?

Tags: cordova, image-processing, cordova-plugins, pci-compliance, card.io

I am trying to use CardIO phonegap plugin : com.keepe.cardio version 1.0.9, I have successfully tested it and seems impressive, my question is how does it scan card? as it capture card image, so where it is stored on device?

I am particularly looking at PCI compliant perspective of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

@Nishikant the card image is never stored on the device, apart from working memory.

The card.io library has been included in many PCI-compliant applications.

Comment: @Dave Goldman  using card.io cordova plugin, do we need to get any app token from card.io, i am trying to build a sample android with card.io cordova plugin, how ever it not bringing up the camera when scanned.